# Ошибка при запуске веб приложения. Tomcat

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, tomcat

Возникает при запуске сервлета. Код и сами исключения описаны ниже. как могу предположить- проблемы с локализацией, но это лишь предположения.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/welcome")
public class ServletController extends HttpServlet {

    PostDao postDao = new PostDao();
    CategoryDao categoryDao = new CategoryDao();

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", request.getLocale());
        response.setHeader("Content-Language", request.getLocale().getLanguage());
        String postId = request.getParameter("post");
        String categoryId = request.getParameter("category");
        String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();

        if (url.contains("newpost")) {
            List<Category> categories = categoryDao.getAll();
            request.setAttribute("categories", categories);
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/newPost.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
            return;
        }

        if (postId != null) {

            Post post = postDao.getById(Long.parseLong(postId));
            request.setAttribute("post", post);
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/post.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        } else {

            List<Post> posts = categoryId == null ?
                    postDao.getAll() :
                    postDao.getPostsByCategoryId(Long.parseLong(categoryId));

            request.setAttribute("posts", posts);
            List<Category> categories = categoryDao.getAll();
            request.setAttribute("categories", categories);
            request.setAttribute("test", resourceBundle.getString("test"));
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/index.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        String title = request.getParameter("title");
        System.out.println("title = " + title);
        String body = request.getParameter("body");
        String summary = request.getParameter("summary");
        String category = request.getParameter("category");

        if (title != null && summary != null && body != null && category != null) {
            Category cat = categoryDao.getById(Long.parseLong(category));

            Post post = new Post(body, summary, title, cat);

            if (id != null) {
                post.setId(Long.parseLong(id));
                postDao.edit(post);
            } else {
                postDao.create(post);

            }
        }

        response.sendRedirect("/blog");

    }
}
```

Исключения в IDE и в Браузере практически идентичны

> 15:17:41,906 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-8) UT005023:
>   Exception handling request to /edu/welcome:
>   java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name
>   messages, locale ru_RU    at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]     at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]     at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:845)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]     at
>   controller.ServletController.doGet(ServletController.java:29)
>   [classes:]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]    at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]   at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден. Причина: отсутствие нужного файла Resource Bundle 'messages'

Comment: пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить Ваш ответ решением(зеленая галка под цифрой слева от ответа).